# Bottom menu overlaps content in Android

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have problem with BottomNavigationViewEx: menu overlaps the bottom part of my activity. I wanted to fix that by adding bottom margin to my content (in that case in ScrollView), but I don't know what is the actual height of BottomNavigationViewEx menu, and even if I would know it, I'm not sure if it is the same (in dp) in all devices. Below my code:

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    ...
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        ...
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <!--
        ...
        content of my activity
        ...
        -->
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ...
            app:menu="@drawable/main_menu"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

How to make the content of my scroll view shorter, to avoid overlaping with bottom menu?

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work by adding:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="<id of bottom nav view>"
```

to the FrameLayout that holds my content.  Here is the entire layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set a value for ScrollView layout_height = "wrap_content". Currently you are setting it to match parent/fill_parent(deprecated) and that is stretching it's content to the height of your layout, in this case ConstraintLayout. If this doesn't help try replacing ConstraintLayout with vertically oriented LinearLayout

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working: after change from fill_parent to wrap_content it looks the same

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing , set the fixed height for bottom menu and set margin bottom to Scrollview, then bottommenu will not overlap your layout.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
...
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    ...
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!--
    ...
    content of my activity
    ...
    -->
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ...
        app:menu="@drawable/main_menu"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I tried it before but this strange BottomNavigationViewEx behaves unpredictly: I fixed height for 45dp and then below menu there appears thin gap - something like bottom margin with about 2px bold. I set marginBottom and paddingBottom to 0, but it looks the same